# PHP Profiling with Blackfire

Tags: php, profiling, blackfire

I am using Blackfire as a profiling tool, but have a doubt.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r9q1ixy56nabi0e/Screenshot%202015-10-19%2010.15.08.png?dl=0

In the above stats, 29630 calls to a function mb_strtolower is happening.

Blackfire analyse the script by calling the it multiple time.

Is 197ms the time from one call or the sum of time taken in all the calls, Kindly suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: What? What was the question?

Comment: Sverri M. Olsen If  you view the image, you'll see mb_strtolower is taking 197 ms. My question is: Is it taking 197 ms in one request or is it sum of time the Profiler hit the url.

Comment: I have no idea. I do not read icons... but around 30k calls to that function would take some time, so it is probably a total of all the calls.

Comment: You should have included the image in your question, since now your dropbox link is dead...

Answer (score 2):

Use xdebug +KCacheGrind tool. The results are very closed to real.

Comment: Or WinCacheGrind if on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

197ms is the total time spent in `mb_strtolower` for your 29630 calls.